# When debugging in Visual Studio and you want to step into a procedure

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging

When debugging in Visual Studio and you want to step into a procedure for example, but you dont want to step into the parameter methods.

Is there a way to do this?

```
var a = StepIntoSomething(getSomeValueDontStepIn(1),getSomeValueDontStepIn(2));
```

Comment: I'd strongly recommend to not use methods in the place of parameters because it deliberately hides side-effects and makes bugs hard-to-find.

Comment: Yep, assign the parameter method calls to variables before you make the call to StepIntoSomething. Problem gone, better code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can use DebuggerStepThroughAttribute.

See this link, [5-very-useful-c-attributes](http://hatim.indexdev.net/2009/12/17/5-very-useful-c-attributes/)